# Where do I find Apache-Passenger config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, apache, passenger

I'm given access to a Rails on a Linux server. According to the server response (the "Server" header), it's working on Apache+Passenger. I need to re-configure it somehow, but I can't find the path where to do it. This path `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` doesn't exist, even `/etc/httpd` doesn't. Where else could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu systems, look in `/etc/apache2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to try and find all the conf files that exist on your server:

find / -type f -name "*.conf"